# How to include CSS/JS files manually for offline use when using Vue.js CLI?

Tags: html, vue.js, asp.net-core, bundling-and-minification, vue-cli

I am using Vue.js CLI with AP.NET Core in a SPA. I have a need to bundle some JS/CSS locally instead of getting it from a CDN since my app may be deployed without internet access. My `public/index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but myapp doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
  </noscript>

  <div id="app"></div>

  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I bundle these for offline use? The confusing part is Vue.js seems to move things into the `dist` directory and categorise things into folders and chunks. I do not know how to manually include my dependencies so they end up in the same way.

[see for my solution showing files into chunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Gyo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
npm i --save bootstrap jquery
npm i --save popper.js (if does not build)
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
```

Then in `main.js`:

```
import './../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import './../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas, far } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';

library.add(fas);
Vue.component('fa-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
```

Use like:

```
<fa-icon icon="users" />
```

If you don't need `far` icons then do not import `far` as it will increase size.